# boost thread::join() in a destructor is warned by a static analysis tool

Tags: c++, threadpool, static-analysis, boost-thread

Joining threads in a destructor works well for me, but it is warned by a static analysis (Coverity).

Here is my threadpool code.

```
class CMyThread {
    // other definitions

    std::vector<boost::thread> threadWorker;

    ~CMyThread(){
        StopThreads();
    }

    void StopThreads(){
        for (auto& t : threadWorker) {
            t.join();
        }
    }
};
```

Actually it works well, but SPA tool warns a possible exception from the function 'join()' because it may throw a 'thread_resource_error' and it is not acceptable for the destructor. The exception appears in the following boost code.

```
void thread::join() {
    if (this_thread::get_id() == get_id())
        boost::throw_exception(thread_resource_error(static_cast<int>(system::errc::resource_deadlock_would_occur), "boost thread: trying joining itself"));

        BOOST_THREAD_VERIFY_PRECONDITION( join_noexcept(),
            thread_resource_error(static_cast<int>(system::errc::invalid_argument), "boost thread: thread not joinable")
        );
    }
}
```

How could I guarantee that there is no 'joining itself' condition? or should I ignore the warning?

Comment: This is the warning message.
exn_spec_violation: An exception of type 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::thread_resource_error> >' is thrown but the throw list 'noexcept' doesn't allow it to be thrown. This will cause a call to 'unexpected()' which usually calls 'terminate()'.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add try/catch in `StopThreads`, won't it help? BTW, shouldn't you use `if(t.joinable()) t.join();` or sth like that?

Comment: Thank you for reply. I tried but it gives the same warning.